# Arrays in Worksheet Funtions

Tags: arrays, excel, countif, worksheet-function

When I run the below code I get only the result from the first match, in this case only the counts of those from "France". Anyone know how to incorporate transpose into the array? Ive tried heaps of different ways.

```
Sub YTDRoutes()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim EuropeArray As Variant
EuropeArray = Array("France", "Egypt", "Belgium", "Greece", "Italy", "Lithuania", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Spain", "Turkey", "United Kingdom")


Worksheets("T Slide").Cells(9, 5) = Application.CountIfs(Worksheets("RIMPORT").Range("Ak1:Ak25000"), Worksheets("T Slide").Cells(4, 2).Value, Worksheets("RIMPORT").Range("Am1:Am25000"), EuropeArray, Worksheets("RIMPORT”).Range("ap1:Ap25000"), ">=" & CLng(Worksheets("T Slide").Cells(1, 5).Value), Worksheets("RIMPORT").Range("ap1:Ap25000"), "<=" & CLng(Worksheets("T Slide").Cells(2, 5).Value))

End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure you include critical tags like `Excel` (if that is what this is for, based on the other tags) or your question will be too obscure to get attention and later editing won't help forcing you to use a bounty for which you have no reputation for.

Answer (score 0):

EuropeArray is a 1 dimensional array with an index from 0 to n-1, and you need to indicate which value you want. EuropeArray(0) is "France", EuropeArray(1) is "Egypt". You could just list each indexed value on the same line, separated by a comma. Note, n-1 represents the numerical index of the last value in the EuropeArray array:

...Range("Am1:Am25000"), EuropeArray(0), EuropeArray(1), EuropeArray(2), EuropeArray(3), EuropeArray(4), EuropeArray(5)...EuropeArray(n-1), Worksheets("RIMPORT”).Range...

Comment: Hey Dugdrown,Thanks for your feedback. You defined it as a one dimensional array. Is there any equvialant in VBA to having all values evaluates {"X","Y","Q"} etc?

Comment: I think what you're asking is whether you can simultaneously refer to all array elements. I'm not familiar with a way to do that. If you want to access array elements I believe you need to refer to them with the hard coded index, e.g., EuropeArray(0), or use a variable to loop through your indices, e.g., For I = 0 to UBOUND(EuropeArray, 1): Debug.print EuropeArray(i): Next i. You could loop through the array and concatenate values in a variable and then include the variable in your output line.

Comment: I see now. Yes, loop through as I mentioned, concatenate array elements in a variable, include commas, include quotation marks around array elements, and add the curly braces on either end of the string in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in `Application.Sumproduct(...)`

```
Sub YTDRoutes()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim EuropeArray As Variant
EuropeArray = Array("France", "Egypt", "Belgium", "Greece", "Italy", "Lithuania", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Spain", "Turkey", "United Kingdom")


Worksheets("T Slide").Cells(9, 5) = Application.SumProduct(Application.CountIfs(Worksheets("RIMPORT").Range("Ak1:Ak25000"), Worksheets("T Slide").Cells(4, 2).Value, Worksheets("RIMPORT").Range("Am1:Am25000"), EuropeArray, Worksheets("RIMPORT”).Range("ap1:Ap25000"), ">=" & CLng(Worksheets("T Slide").Cells(1, 5).Value), Worksheets("RIMPORT").Range("ap1:Ap25000"), "<=" & CLng(Worksheets("T Slide").Cells(2, 5).Value)))

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Scott, This worked a treat. Without sounding like a dingbat, how does it know to move onto the next variable in the array? I did nothing other than embedd it in sum product and it worked?

Comment: The countifs returns an array of values.  without sumproduct to addup the array it just returns the first value as a cell can only hold one value.  If this worked, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: ah, ok, similar to the double urinary --. Thanks so much for the help both "scott craner" & budgrown